# passenger not starting up but don't really see an error

Tags: passenger, redmine

I tried to follow this:

https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-install-redmine-on-centos-7

I think I had it working on my own little centos7 box here.  Though it seems it never comes up and always exits in the /var/log/httpd/error_log but don't see why. I do see two warnings but to me those shouldn't effect it starting up?  Does any extra set of eyes see anything in this log?

```
[Wed May 08 15:12:53.300528 2019] [suexec:notice] [pid 26924] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[ N 2019-05-08 15:12:53.3486 26926/T1 age/Wat/WatchdogMain.cpp:1366 ]: Starting Passenger watchdog...
[ N 2019-05-08 15:12:53.3860 26929/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1339 ]: Starting Passenger core...
[ N 2019-05-08 15:12:53.3863 26929/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:256 ]: Passenger core running in multi-application mode.
[ W 2019-05-08 15:12:53.4070 26929/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1006 ]: WARNING: potential privilege escalation vulnerability detected. Phusion Passenger is running as root, and part(s) of the Passenger root path (/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/passenger-6.0.2) can be changed by non-root user(s):

 - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/passenger-6.0.2 is not secure: it can be modified by group rvm
 - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems is not secure: it can be modified by group rvm
 - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3 is not secure: it can be modified by group rvm
 - /usr/local/rvm/gems is not secure: it can be modified by group rvm
 - /usr/local/rvm is not secure: it can be modified by group rvm

Please either fix up the permissions for the insecure paths, or install Passenger in a different location that can only be modified by root.
[ N 2019-05-08 15:12:53.4071 26929/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1014 ]: Passenger core online, PID 26929

[ N 2019-05-08 15:12:53.6931 26929/T8 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:671 ]: Signal received. Gracefully shutting down... (send signal 2 more time(s) to force shutdown)
[ N 2019-05-08 15:12:53.6931 26929/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1245 ]: Received command to shutdown gracefully. Waiting until all clients have disconnected...
[ N 2019-05-08 15:12:53.6932 26929/Ta Ser/Server.h:902 ]: [ServerThr.2] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2019-05-08 15:12:53.6932 26929/Ta Ser/Server.h:558 ]: [ServerThr.2] Shutdown finished
[ N 2019-05-08 15:12:53.6933 26929/T8 Ser/Server.h:902 ]: [ServerThr.1] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2019-05-08 15:12:53.6933 26929/T8 Ser/Server.h:558 ]: [ServerThr.1] Shutdown finished
[ N 2019-05-08 15:12:53.6933 26929/Tc Ser/Server.h:902 ]: [ServerThr.3] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2019-05-08 15:12:53.6933 26929/Te Ser/Server.h:902 ]: [ServerThr.4] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2019-05-08 15:12:53.6933 26929/Tc Ser/Server.h:558 ]: [ServerThr.3] Shutdown finished
[ N 2019-05-08 15:12:53.6933 26929/Te Ser/Server.h:558 ]: [ServerThr.4] Shutdown finished
[ N 2019-05-08 15:12:53.6938 26929/Tg Ser/Server.h:902 ]: [ApiServer] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2019-05-08 15:12:53.6938 26929/Tg Ser/Server.h:558 ]: [ApiServer] Shutdown finished
WARNING: PassengerRoot cannot occur within <VirtualHost> section
[Wed May 08 15:12:53.732238 2019] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 26924] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[ N 2019-05-08 15:12:53.7823 26956/T1 age/Wat/WatchdogMain.cpp:1366 ]: Starting Passenger watchdog...
[ N 2019-05-08 15:12:53.8208 26959/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1339 ]: Starting Passenger core...
[ N 2019-05-08 15:12:53.8211 26959/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:256 ]: Passenger core running in multi-application mode.
[ W 2019-05-08 15:12:53.8418 26959/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1006 ]: WARNING: potential privilege escalation vulnerability detected. Phusion Passenger is running as root, and part(s) of the Passenger root path (/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/passenger-6.0.2) can be changed by non-root user(s):

 - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/passenger-6.0.2 is not secure: it can be modified by group rvm
 - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems is not secure: it can be modified by group rvm
 - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3 is not secure: it can be modified by group rvm
 - /usr/local/rvm/gems is not secure: it can be modified by group rvm
 - /usr/local/rvm is not secure: it can be modified by group rvm

Please either fix up the permissions for the insecure paths, or install Passenger in a different location that can only be modified by root.
[ N 2019-05-08 15:12:53.8418 26959/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1014 ]: Passenger core online, PID 26959
[Wed May 08 15:12:53.842702 2019] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 26924] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Wed May 08 15:12:53.924503 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 26924] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) Phusion_Passenger/6.0.2 mod_auth_gssapi/1.5.1 mod_nss/1.0.14 NSS/3.28.4 mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.5 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed May 08 15:12:53.924564 2019] [core:notice] [pid 26924] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[ N 2019-05-08 15:12:54.4980 26929/T1 age/Cor/TelemetryCollector.h:531 ]: Message from Phusion: End time can not be before or equal to begin time
[ N 2019-05-08 15:12:54.5497 26929/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1324 ]: Passenger core shutdown finished
[ N 2019-05-08 15:12:57.5521 26959/T5 age/Cor/SecurityUpdateChecker.h:519 ]: Security update check: no update found (next check in 24 hours)
```

I edited the 00-base.conf as indicated in the link, and the redmine.conf same, with the right paths that were displayed by the

`passenger-install-apache2-module`

command as described on the site too.

not sure what else to check or do, I did disable SELinux too.

Comment: It looks like permissions problem, have you tried doing that as root, or sudo?

Comment: So when I run sudo systemctl restart httpd is when I get that error.  I also think it might be a DNS issue.  It does seem to mostly work, as I can hit the redmine server using the ip address, but not the whatever.something.com address I set in the vhosts config.  I will investigate further, I am glad it isn't a total loss.

Comment: but, have you done sudo passenger-install-apache2-module, because seems to me it's not starting because of this: Please either fix up the permissions for the insecure paths, or install Passenger in a different location that can only be modified by root.